# Angular UI Router - Access Custom Data in Children's Resolve {}

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

How come this Inherited Custom Data `data` is not accessible in the child state `main.loadbalancer.vips` in the `resolve: {}` function `hello`?

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer", ["ui.bootstrap", "ui.router"]).config(function($stateProvider) {
  return $stateProvider.state("main.loadbalancer", {
    data: { readonly : false },
    url: "device/:id",
    views: {
      "content@": {
        templateUrl: "loadbalancer/loadbalancer.html",
        controller: "LoadBalancerCtrl"
      }
    }
  }).state("main.loadbalancer.vips", {
    url: "/vips",
    templateUrl: "loadbalancer/vip-table.html",
    resolve: {
      hello: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    },
    controller: "VipListCtrl"
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `this.data`...

```
  }).state("main.loadbalancer.vips", {
    url: "/vips",
    templateUrl: "loadbalancer/vip-table.html",
    resolve: {
      hello: function() {
        console.log(this.data);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That data should be accessible in the $state object if you inject it ($state):

```
$state.$current.data.readonly
```

Comment: typically yes, but not in my case for that moment in code execution